# Making an ArrayList containing objects (Ellipses, Rectangles etc.)

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, geometry, ellipse

I am creating a program for a school project where the user can create a geometrical shape (which is supposed to look like a horse) using buttons which control the size and color of: One Ellipse, one Circle, two Rectangles and one String (as a title for the figure). To save the figure I want an ArrayList where all of these are included, so I created a class which looks like this.

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class WiLi_Horse{

    Ellipse body;
    Rectangle leg1;
    Rectangle leg2;
    Circle head;
    String name;

    public WiLi_Horse(Ellipse bdy, 
            Rectangle lg1, Rectangle lg2, 
            Circle hd, String nme) {

        body = bdy;
        leg1 = lg1;
        leg2 = lg2;
        head = hd;
        name = nme;
    }
}
```

Now, when I create the ArrayList I write the following (in another class):

```
ArrayList<WiLi_Horse> horseList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then want to add a 'horse' in the ArrayList, so I begin with typing:

```
horseList.add(new WiLi_Horse(XXX);
```

Where it says 'XXX' is the problem in hand. I don't know what to write from here on. Eclipse's quick-fix is to add null, null, null, null, null, but that is ofcourse not what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is XXX? Is that line really compiling?

Comment: @Bex No, it is not, I just do not know what to write in between the brackets.

Comment: Why do you want an `ArrayList`?  It seems like you only need a single `WiLi_Horse` object.

Comment: @pathfinderelite I only use an ArrayList because I am a beginner Java programmer. But if I make a WiLi_Horse object, will it store all the information about the shapes that i desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try a `List` of `Shape` which will accept all of them:

```
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

Now you can add whatever shape you want to add:

```
shapes.add(body);
shapes.add(leg1);
shapes.add(leg2);
```

etc. Here is the complete example which you can test:

```
public class WiLi_Horse {
    Ellipse body;
    Rectangle leg1;
    Rectangle leg2;
    Circle head;
    String name;

    public WiLi_Horse(Ellipse body, Rectangle leg1, Rectangle leg2, Circle head, String name) {
        this.body = body;
        this.leg1 = leg1;
        this.leg2 = leg2;
        this.head = head;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Shape> getHorse()
    {
        List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        shapes.add(body);
        shapes.add(leg1);
        shapes.add(leg2);
        shapes.add(head);
        return shapes;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WiLi_Horse{" +
                "body=" + body +
                ", leg1=" + leg1 +
                ", leg2=" + leg2 +
                ", head=" + head +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now you can test it as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(10,20);
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(40,20);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(40,20);
        Circle circle = new Circle(5);
        String name = "Horse";

        WiLi_Horse horse1 = new WiLi_Horse(ellipse,rect1,rect2,circle,name);
        WiLi_Horse horse2 = new WiLi_Horse(ellipse,rect1,rect2,circle,name);
        WiLi_Horse horse3 = new WiLi_Horse(ellipse,rect1,rect2,circle,name);
        WiLi_Horse horse4 = new WiLi_Horse(ellipse,rect1,rect2,circle,name);

        List<WiLi_Horse> horseList = new ArrayList<>();
        horseList.add(horse1);
        horseList.add(horse2);
        horseList.add(horse3);
        horseList.add(horse4);
        System.out.println(horseList);
    }
```

Comment: Will this work if I later want to display the shapes in another scene for example? Will the List be able to store such information as size, x- and y-coordinates and Color?

Comment: @Axeln as list stores objects, all information is stored in each particular object is also "stored" in a list.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I am not entirely sure if I understand your response, just because I am not that good in Java programming. Could you give me an example-code, or something similar?